# sum the elements of node sets in xslt 1.0

Tags: xslt

I have the following xml whose structure is same but the nodes and there values can be diffrent :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?>
<main>
    <_All>
        <_001372>
            <_2012-Oct-10>
                <Employee_Amount>1.0</Employee_Amount>
                <Combo_Savings_Amount>2.0</Combo_Savings_Amount>
                <Total_Sales>3.0</Total_Sales>
                <Dine_in_Amount>4.0</Dine_in_Amount>
                <Promos_Actual>5.0</Promos_Actual>
                <Cash_Count>6.0</Cash_Count>
                </_2012-Oct-10>
            <_2012-Oct-11>
                <Employee_Amount>7.0</Employee_Amount>
                <Combo_Savings_Amount>0.0</Combo_Savings_Amount>
                <Total_Sales>0.0</Total_Sales>
                <Dine_in_Amount>0.0</Dine_in_Amount>
                <Promos_Actual>0.0</Promos_Actual>
                <Cash_Count>0.0</Cash_Count>
                </_2012-Oct-11>
            </_001372>
        <_024139>
            <_2012-Oct-10>
                <Employee_Amount>0.0</Employee_Amount>
                <Combo_Savings_Amount>313.148999999997</Combo_Savings_Amount>
                <Total_Sales>3515.5</Total_Sales>
                <Dine_in_Amount>543.86</Dine_in_Amount>
                <Promos_Actual>0.0</Promos_Actual>
                <Cash_Count>330.0</Cash_Count>
                </_2012-Oct-10>
            <_2012-Oct-11>
                <Employee_Amount>10.0</Employee_Amount>
                <Combo_Savings_Amount>17.0</Combo_Savings_Amount>
                <Total_Sales>5.0</Total_Sales>
                <Dine_in_Amount>7.0</Dine_in_Amount>
                <Promos_Actual>0.0</Promos_Actual>
                <Cash_Count>20.0</Cash_Count>
                </_2012-Oct-11>
            </_024139>
        <_101010>
            <_2012-Oct-10>
                <Employee_Amount>5.0</Employee_Amount>
                <Combo_Savings_Amount>0.0</Combo_Savings_Amount>
                <Total_Sales>0.0</Total_Sales>
                <Dine_in_Amount>0.0</Dine_in_Amount>
                <Promos_Actual>0.0</Promos_Actual>
                <Cash_Count>0.0</Cash_Count>
                </_2012-Oct-10>
            <_2012-Oct-11>
                <Employee_Amount>0.0</Employee_Amount>
                <Combo_Savings_Amount>0.0</Combo_Savings_Amount>
                <Total_Sales>0.0</Total_Sales>
                <Dine_in_Amount>0.0</Dine_in_Amount>
                <Promos_Actual>0.0</Promos_Actual>
                <Cash_Count>0.0</Cash_Count>
                </_2012-Oct-11>
            </_101010>
    </_All>
</main>
```

I need to sum all the elements of a store. for example i need to sum Employee_Amount of dates date01 and date02. same as all the nodes. What I have try is as below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1"
            align="center">
            <tr bgcolor="#8181F7">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/*/*/*" mode="ColHeader" />
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="#00FFFF">
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="translate(name(child::*),'_',' ')" />
                </td>
                <td>&#160;</td>
                <xsl:for-each select="/*[1]/*[1]/*[1]/*[1]/*">
                    <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of
                            select='format-number(sum(/*/*/*/*/*[$pos]),"#.##")' />
                    </td>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/*/*" mode="values" />
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*/*/*/*" mode="ColHeader">
        <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
            <th>Region</th>
            <th>Store</th>
            <xsl:for-each select="./*">
                <th>
                    <xsl:value-of select="translate(name(),'_',' ')" />
                </th>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/*/*/*" mode="values">
        <xsl:for-each select=".">
            <tr>
                <td>&#160;</td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="translate(name(),'_',' ')" />
                </td>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="./*/*" mode="rollupVal"/>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/*/*/*/*/*" mode="rollupVal">
        <xsl:variable name="pos1" select="current()"/>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select='format-number(sum(./node()[$pos1]), "#.##")'/>
                    </td>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But I am unable to sum those rows. Please help me. Thanks

Edited: The output HTML is:

```
<table align="center" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#8181F7">
    <th>Region</th><th>Store</th><th>Employee Amount</th><th>Combo Savings Amount</th><th>Total Sales</th><th>Dine in Amount</th><th>Promos Actual</th><th>Cash Count</th>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#00FFFF">
        <td> All</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>18</td>
        <td>332.15</td>
        <td>3523.5</td>
        <td>554.86</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>356</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td> 001372 44CLOSED</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td> 024139</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>330.15</td>
        <td>3520.5</td>
        <td>550.86</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>350</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What would be the expected output?

Comment: I need to sum the elements like Employee_amount of all the dates in a store. for example this should be 8(1+7) for Employe_amount for the date date01, 10 for date02 and  so on for all the nodes in a particular date.

Comment: Please add an example of the desired output HTML to your question.

Comment: Hi JLRishe, I have updated my question with the desire output html.

Comment: Thanks.  I've added an answer below.  I don't know where you got the 001372 44CLOSED and 024139 values.  Those don't seem to be anywhere in the source XML.

Comment: I have edited my original xml to make it short. thats why these fields are not shown there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XSL is still a bit of a mess, but it seems to produce the expected output:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:key name="field" match="/*/*/*/*/*" use="local-name()" />
  <xsl:variable name="fieldGroups" select="/*/*/*/*/*[generate-id() = generate-id(key('field', local-name())[1])]" />

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1"
        align="center">
      <tr bgcolor="#8181F7">
        <!-- First date node -->
        <xsl:call-template name="ColHeaders" />
      </tr>
      <!-- All node -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="GrandTotal" />
      <!-- Each store -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*/*" mode="values" />
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="EmptyCell">
    <td>&#160;</td>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*/*" mode="GrandTotal">
    <tr bgcolor="#00FFFF">
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(name(.),'_',' ')" />
      </td>
      <xsl:call-template name="EmptyCell" />
      <!-- Each field of first date -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$fieldGroups" mode="FieldTotal" />
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match='/*/*/*/*/*' mode='FieldTotal'>
    <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select='format-number(sum(key("field", local-name())),"0.##")' />
    </td>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="ColHeaders">
    <th>Region</th>
    <th>Store</th>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$fieldGroups" mode="ColHeader" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="ColHeader">
    <th>
      <xsl:value-of select="translate(name(),'_',' ')" />
    </th>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Matches stores -->
  <xsl:template match="/*/*/*" mode="values">
    <tr>
      <xsl:call-template name="EmptyCell" />
      <td>
        <!-- Store code -->
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(name(),'_',' ')" />
      </td>
      <!-- All fields in first date -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1]/*" mode="rollupVal"/>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*/*/*/*/*" mode="rollupVal">
    <xsl:variable name="pos1" select="position()"/>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select='format-number(sum(../../*/*[$pos1]), "0.##")'/>
    </td>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

output:

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" align="center">
  <tr bgcolor="#8181F7">
    <th>Region</th>
    <th>Store</th>
    <th>Employee Amount</th>
    <th>Combo Savings Amount</th>
    <th>Total Sales</th>
    <th>Dine in Amount</th>
    <th>Promos Actual</th>
    <th>Cash Count</th>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#00FFFF">
    <td> All</td>
    <td> </td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>332.14</td>
    <td>3523.5</td>
    <td>554.86</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>356</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> </td>
    <td> store01</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> </td>
    <td> store02</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>330.14</td>
    <td>3520.5</td>
    <td>550.86</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>350</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi JLRishe, sum is good but when apply your template with my xsl, it produces some extra td with 0 value to it.

Comment: I applied the XSL to the XML you provided and the result is shown above. Are you referring to the result from a different input XML?

Comment: I have updated the source XML with the original one. and this XML is generated by DB, so its nodes can be change but its structure remain same. so i can not use any contains  which you have used in the answer. it is fine but the output contains extra td with the value 0 to it for bothe the value rows. Thanks

Comment: Ok, please try the updated XSLT. I have verified it on your new XML.

Comment: Hi JLRishe, Could you please suggest me any book to study XSLT 1.0. I am new to it.